# How to find the proper EPON stick that works with my ISP?

Tags: home-networking, network-adapter, fiber

Though my ISP has provided an ONU works really well, but I still want to replace it with a Mikrotik RB962UiGS Router which has an SFP port. 
Now I have everything(LOID, MAC, TR069 credentials, etc.) needed to replace the ONU, but not sure about the EPON sticks, what should I be looking at when shopping these?

Comment: Ask the ISP for these parameters as well? They know best.

Comment: @grawity I already have all the parameters. My ISP, however, would not recommend any model.